# jquery autocomplete this.source is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've implemented autocomplete on an input field, but the box does not show up and firebug returns "this.source is not a function". I've used autocomplete on other fields of the same page without any problems. (two textarea's).

I'm using the following code to debug, same effect if I run from script file or Firebug command line.

```
var fakedata = ['test1','test2','test3','test4','ietsanders'];
$("#omschrijving").autocomplete(fakedata);
```

running jquery 1.4.2 and jquery ui 1.8.2, both minified versions.

Does anyone have an idea how autocomplete works fine on the textareas but causes this malfunctioning on inputs?

Error & Stack trace:

```
this.source is not a function
http://facturatie.autodealers.nl/dev/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js
Line 570
close(Object { name="a"})jquery....min.js (regel 570)
close(Object { name="a"}, Object { name="c"})jquery....min.js (regel 570)
response()
```

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin are you using?  There are several variants.

Comment: Could you turn on stack tracing in firebug and post the function in which this occured?

Comment: I'm using the jQuery UI autocomplete as bundled in version 1.8.2 of the jQuery UI library.
working on the stack tracing

Comment: And I found the answer, almost to embarrassed to admit that I just implemented it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Answer is that the first parameter of the autocomplete should be an object containing the "source" property. This works

```
var fakedata = ['test1','test2','test3','test4','ietsanders'];
$("#omschrijving").autocomplete({source:fakedata});
```

Comment: not so embarrassing, as it says different in some documentation. How where you to guess?

Comment: Also, you may see this error or similar if `source` is an object with keys, like `{ a:A, b:B, c:C }`. Should be just single values, as in `{ "A", "B", "C" }`.

Comment: In my case,` $(".div").autocomplete();` I was having this error because class `.div` didn't exist

Answer (score 14):

If you were trying to use autocomplete from http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/#demo, it now collides with the autocomplete method in jQuery UI. I had the same problem and later noticed that I could just use the jQuery UI implementation.

(NOTE: It appears that this page's documentation is wrong: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete#Setup)

Answer (score 14):

If you use it with jQuery UI library it also has plugin named `autocomplete`. In this case you can use plugin alias `devbridgeAutocomplete`:

```
$('.autocomplete').devbridgeAutocomplete({ ... });
```

This solve the problem with jQuery UI collision

Comment: This should get more ticks because that solved my problem.

Comment: This solved my issue too.  Crazy.  Oh, Stack Overflow, how I love thee (most of the time).

Comment: Exactly where and how to put it in my js code? please help @tjans

Comment: It's been so long, I don't even remember.  I don't have that old code anymore, and don't use jquery anymore (React, FTW!).  Sorry I can't be of more assistance.

Answer (score 5):

As Shelton stated, the version from devbridge.com (1.1.3) collides with jQuery UI (1.8.4).  Got it working by making sure the devbridge version loads after jQuery UI's version.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem for tagedit/autocomplete. It seems you also want to disable the autocomplete. Setting the source to false avoids these errors.

Solution:

```
options.autocompleteOptions.source = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Search at the end of **jquery.autocomplete.js** the following section:

Create chainable jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.devbridgeAutocomplete = function (options, args) {....
```

This devbridgeAutocomplete is an alternative plugin to access to the same functionality using this lines:

```
if (!$.fn.autocomplete) {
    $.fn.autocomplete = $.fn.devbridgeAutocomplete;
}
```

So.. you can use `devbridgeAutocomplete` instead of **autocomplete** or any name by changing this `$.fn.devbridgeAutocomplete`

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had a second import of jquery which I didn't realize.
Something like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.27/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script> 

// More code

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

So be sure to import the autocomplete script after you initialized jquery.