# Setting the source of autocomplete remotely

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery autocomplete this.source is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308935/jquery-autocomplete-this-source-is-not-a-function-error)

I have an autocomplete which I want to hook upto my API to return all customer account numbers. The problem is my API returns an object: AccountNumber, InvoiceNumber, Name, Address etc.. When I try to make my source the AccountNumber only, like below:

```
$.getJSON('/api/Customers', function(data) {
    $("#AccountNumber").autocomplete({
        source: data.AccountNumber,
        minLength: 4
    });
});
```

I get back this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

Any ideas what Im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the callback is returning an Object, you must pull the data and place it in an arary.  As long as `data` is an array of Account Objects, you could try this:

```
$.getJSON('/api/Customers', function(data) {
    var acctNums = [];
    for(a in data) {
        acctNums.push(data[a].AccountNumber);
    }   

    $("#AccountNumber").autocomplete({
        source: acctNums,
        minLength: 4
    });
});
```

Another option would be to just add a different Request route that would only return an array of customer account numbers. That way you can just pass it as such:

```
$.getJSON('/api/Customers/AccountNums', function(data) {
    $("#AccountNumber").autocomplete({
        source: data,
        minLength: 4
    });
});
```

Finally, you could let the [jQuery UI plugin handle the calls](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#overview-main).  You'll need to create a different request route that returns an array of JSON objects only for Autocomplete (each contain `value` and `label` properties). Then just use the absolute or relative URL of your route to get the data. Below is a small example:

```
$("#AccountNumber").autocomplete({
    // This GET Request returns an Array of Objects used for Auto-Complete:
    // [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
    source: '/api/Customers/AccountNumsAuto',
    minLength: 4
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The source attribute of the jQuery UI autocomplete must be :

- An array of results :
   `source : ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]`
- A string (the url of the remote PHP page which process the query), this will trigger an ajax request to this page, with the parameter named `term` which contains the search value :
   `source : "page.php"`
- A function called with 2 parameters `request` and `response`. The first one contains the value of the search (`request.term`), the second contains an object that you have to fill with the values.

You should read the jQuery UI [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). 

In your case you can transform your JSon into an array of results.