# jQuery autocomplete ui with json issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the jquery autocomplete ui to work but without success. There is no list of matches presented. I'm getting the error "TypeError: this.source is not a function"

so far I have an input field `<input type="text" id="searchbar" name="title" placeholder="Search">`

and then in my script I have

I'm not getting this to work. anyone have any ideas of where I can begin to troubleshoot? I really have a hard time with the jquery ui documentation.

Comment: change `source: "data",` to `source: data,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to use this code for your autocomplete:

```
$("#searchbar").autocomplete({
    source: "php/searchbar.php",
    minLength: 3
});
```

You don't have to do an extra ajax request. The plugin it self does the ajax request.

You have an missing hash in your autocomplete selector too:
`$("searchbar")` vs. `$("#searchbar")`

I have created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9rtu412g/

Source from documentation here: 
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote (view source)

For your jQuery version: 
 `<script src="js/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Use this jQuery UI version:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js

I hope I could help you to solve your problem.

Comment: With this, in my html <script></script> instead of a seperate JS file, I get the error "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function"

Comment: TypeError: $(...).on is not a function - <script src="js/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Polarbearz Updated. I hope you are using jQuery UI 1.11.4  (Legacy, for jQuery1.6+) or lower for autocomplete?

Comment: Using the code you have given it is now working without errors, and displaying the results like this: http://puu.sh/vzYwk/806628ecd5.png . I am greatful for your help, I just need to display the results in a better way somehow now. For some reason I also can't click on the result and be linked to the page/event.

Comment: @Polarbearz have you added the CSS file from the jQuery UI package to your page? Like this: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css

Comment: That's now changed it to make it a little bit better. I made a topic here wondering if anybody knew how to change it from navigating along the results with arrow keys, to being able to click one directly when a suggestion shows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705210/jquery-autocomplete-ui-results-navigation-with-arrow-keys-issue- this is how it looks now with the css - http://puu.sh/vAR0U/1d0f0473ea.png - http://puu.sh/vAR0s/79ac235291.png - you can't click on the suggestion you have to navigate through with the arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

At first console.log your data to check is there any data returned from ajax request then remove double quote from your data variable.

```
 source: "data"(wrong)
 source: data(right)
```

wish it helps

Comment: I changed this, and now I am getting the error: TypeError: this.source is not a function - according to this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308935/jquery-autocomplete-this-source-is-not-a-function-error, the data needs to be put inside a variable, and I've updated my JS above, whilst still getting the error.