# JQuery autocomplete ui results navigation with arrow keys issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've managed to get the jquery autocomplete ui to work and I've been able to set a link correctly, the only issue is that, instead of being able to click on the suggested results, you have to use the arrow keys to navigate through them. I've further added the jQuery UI css package. queryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images look like you have an CSS z-index problem, try to add this to your CSS file:

```
.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget-content { 
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

This should fix the problem.

Your user information overlays the suggestionlist, so you are not able to click the items. Are these information absolute or relative positioned?

Comment: Ok floating should not be the problem. Can you post the HTML and CSS for this part?

Comment: Adding that css fixed it! You can now click the links! sick, ty vm for all of your help, couldn't have done any of it without you, One highly clickable result: http://puu.sh/vAWEr/7d7823965b.png